# Python- Finding out what values can/ can't be changed using ttk.Style

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, ttk

I'm quite new in Python, so perhaps it is a non-question, although an intensive search was made, leaving me empty handed.

I'm using a table of `ttk.Entry`- and wish to have all text centered. While using `style.configure('TEntry', foreground='green', justify=tk.CENTER)` - text was not centered,

but instead, moving `justify=tk.CENTER` into widgets lines `ent1 = ttk.Entry(root, textvariable=t, width=20, justify=tk.CENTER)`, it worked **OK**.

In similar way, `font=('Helvetica', 18)` was affecting text when noted in `ent=...`

Looking for an answer regarding when can/can't I use certain config values in `ttk.Style` [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tkinter.ttk.html) and in [Using and customizing ttk styles](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-style-layer.html) left me unanswered.

Any lead ?

Comment: Did you actually *use* the `style` to create widgets?

Comment: @RolandSmith yes. For example- the text does color does apply when configured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, noting that especially ttky entry widget styling has some inconsistencies. A rule of thumb I use is: If `ttkentry.configure()` returns a configuration option (as in this case `justify`), then use `ttkentry.configure(justify='center')` or whatever valid option you want. Ttk entry fonts are in the same category. You set the font on them using the `ttkentry.configure(font='???')` method.

So in this case, the response to typing ttkentry.configure is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()
ttkentry = ttk.Entry(root)
ttkentry.insert(0, "my centered text")
ttkentry.pack()
ttkentry.configure()
# Partial output of ttkentry.configure()
{'foreground': ('foreground', 'textColor', 'TextColor', '', ''),..., 'justify': ('justify', 'justify', 'Justify', <index object: 'left'>, 'left'),...,'validate': ('validate', 'validate', 'Validate', <index object: 'none'>, 'none')}

# After this command, note that the text is centered.
ttkentry.configure(justify='center')
```

Comment: Appreciate your response. My question was about using `ttk.Style()`. Correct me if I'm wrong ( and newbie ), but using `ttkentry.configure()` is same as when `ttkentry=ttk.Entry(root, justify=CENTER)`, and is good only for the specific widget, and in my case I have multiple Entry time table.

Comment: Yes, and that is the problem with the inconsistency -- you cannot style entries completely using only styles :(    ...But you can use the option database to accomplish the same thing `root.option_add('*Entry.Font', ['Consolas', 18])` for example.

Comment: BTW option_add works only for un-styled (regular tkinter) widgets.